# Maven dependency:tree class not found error

Tags: java, maven

I'm using Maven version 3.3.9 to build my project. I know I've got a dependency problem (an old version of a library is being pulled in) so I'd like to use the dependency tree to see what's going on. My problem is that when I run `mvn dependency:tree` I get the following error:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.5.1:tree (default-cli) @ data-access ---
[WARNING] Error injecting:org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.internal.Maven3DependencyGraphBuilder
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonatype/aether/version/VersionConstraint
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2570)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1855)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:688)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:380)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:164)

            <some lines removed for clarity>

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.aether.version.VersionConstraint
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 63 more

            <more lines removed for clarity>

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.5.1:tree (default-cli) on project myProjectName: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.5.1:tree failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.5.1:tree: org/sonatype/aether/version/VersionConstraint
```

why wouldn't maven be pulling in the code it requires? How do we fix it?

Comment: @soorapadman - You are right this is a duplicate. I did try to Google the question first - Honestly!

Comment: its all right buddy .